# get string data from sqlserver db table and pass to an arraylist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, arraylist

Is there a quick way to query a database table in c# and push all the results into an arrayList?

Thanks

Comment: possibly.  why do u ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server you can use LINQ. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

Answer (score 0):

I like to use [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) for database access. Once you have the libraries included in your project and a connection string defined in app.config it's very easy to run simple queries and map them to lists;

app.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" connectionString="server=LOCALHOST;database=MyDb; integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

C#

```
class MyTable
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
}

var db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("Default");
var genericList = db.ExecuteSqlStringAccessor<MyTable>("select * from mytable").ToList();
```

Comment: you don't end up with an `ArrayList` there, you end up with a `List`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. If you really want an `ArrayList` you can do `var arrayList = new ArrayList(genericList);`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by guess and check. Can anyone verify that this code is relatively sound?

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM compsTickers", con);

        SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            tickerList.Add(reader.GetString(0));

        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();
```